# Problem proving link between convexity and first derivative being monotonic

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

I'm having trouble completing a proof of a well-known theorem: suppose a real-valued function $f$ is differentiable in $I$; if $f$ is strictly convex in $I$ then $f'$ is strictly increasing in $I$. (I only have a problem proving this part of the theorem; the converse case is okay.)

The definition I use for convexity is this one: $\forall x_1<x_2<x_3 \in I: \frac{ f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}<\frac{ f(x_3)-f(x_2)}{x_3-x_2}$.

I started the proof as follows. Choose $x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4 \in I$. Then $\frac{ f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}<\frac{ f(x_3)-f(x_2)}{x_3-x_2}<\frac{ f(x_4)-f(x_3)}{x_4-x_3}$, as $f$ is strictly convex on $I$. Hence: $\frac{ f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}<\frac{ f(x_4)-f(x_3)}{x_4-x_3}$.

Now let $x_2 \rightarrow x_1^+$ and $x_3 \rightarrow x_4^-$. As $f$ is differentiable in $I$, the left hand of the last inequality becomes $f'(x_1)$ and the right hand becomes $f'(x_4)$.

My problem is this: how can I be sure that $f'(x_1) < f'(x_4)$ and not $f'(x_1) \leq  f'(x_4)$? I would like to stick to the abovementioned definition of convexity, if possible.

Thank you for your help.